Hibernate Search compatibility issue in Spring Boot Pom.xml
I am using Spring Boot v3.3.1 and Java 17 I am trying to use the below Hibernate Search dependency to use @Indexed annotation and @Field annotation, TermVector in my entity class and other Search related methods.
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.12.Final</version>
</dependency>

After adding the above dependency, I am getting the below error -
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.<init>(SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.java:96)

The following method did not exist:

'org.hibernate.MultiTenancyStrategy org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions.getMultiTenancyStrategy()'

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore, was loaded from the following location:

jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-orm/5.11.12.Final/hibernate-search-orm-5.11.12.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/search/cfg/impl/SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore.class

The called method's class, org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.5.2.Final/hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/Dell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.33.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.33.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.5.2.Final/hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.SearchConfigurationFromHibernateCore and org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions

Below is my Pom.xml file dependencies
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>

I have tried a lot of solutions provided by other folks but none worked so far. Is there a better way to invoke the search related methods like EntityManager?

Use a compatible version, see https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix for a compatibility matrix.

I'd suggest looking at the getting started guide at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/7.2/getting-started/orm/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted-dependencies where the use of BOM is explained to simplify dependency management.
Then you want to use at least the Hibernate Search 6.2 (with -orm6 artifacts) or the currently latest 7.2. See the compatibility matrix to match your ORM version https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix
Spring Boot is using a Hibernate ORM 6.x series so it won't work with Hibernate Search 5.x...
